# How to allocate and copy 2D arrays between host and device in CUDA correctly

Tags: arrays, cuda

Is it possible to copy a 2D host array allocated like that

```
h_A=(int**)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   h_A[i]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
}
```

to 2D device array allocated like that

```
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_A, &pitch, 3*sizeof(int), N);
```

I've tried to copy from host to device and back to host to check if the process worked and the result was that only the 2 first rows copied correctly

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXpChyYd2Div0pDjTRxZhwYd7GHRfjXN/view?usp=sharing

**Copy from host array h_A to device array d_A**

```
cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, h_A, 3*sizeof(int), 3*sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

**Copy from device array d_A to host array d_B**

```
cudaMemcpy2D(h_B, pitch, d_A, 3*sizeof(int), 3*sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: "Is it possible to copy a 2D host array allocated like that" -- the first point to make is that the "2D" array is no such thing. It is an array of pointers. And no, it isn't possible to do as you are trying. `cudaMemcpy2D` is exclusively for copying pitched linear memory. You don't have that  as a source

Comment: @talonmies I am in need of the form of the host array, so is there a way to copy such an array from host to device

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate an array of pointers to store rows, like this:

```
h_A=(int**)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   h_A[i]=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
}
```

then to allocate and move that to a comparable device side structure using conventional device memory requires this:

```
dh_A=(int**)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   int* p; 
   cudaMalloc(&p, 3*sizeof(int))
   cudaMemcpy(p, h_A[i], 3*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   dh_A[i]=p;
}

int** d_A = cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeof(int*) * N);
cudaMemcpy(d_A, dh_A, N*sizeof(int*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

[Note: all code written in browser, not guaranteed to compile or work correctly]

I will leave it as an exercise to the reader how to perform the device to host copy. At this point you might conclude that it is simpler to just use linear memory on both the host and device. It will be simpler *and* faster.